# Error "Object reference not set..." in .NET System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase

Tags: asp.net, .net, powershell, nullreferenceexception

I have some older ASP.NET application that is using System.Management.Automation to execute Powershell Scripts using some code like:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
```

I can write a test application with a test powershell script that only takes 2 parameters and returns an echo to the .NET application like:

```
Param(
$param1 = $(Throw [System.ArgumentNullException]"Param1"), #Parameter 1
$param2 = $(Throw [System.ArgumentNullException]"Param2") #Parameter 2
)
[string]$cmd = "Echo"

[string]$command = $cmd + " 'dir " + $param1 + " " + $param2 + "'"

invoke-expression $command
```

If I execute the script about 10.000 times within the ASP.NET application I often get the following error:

```
[NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.]
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(String variable, EnvironmentVariableTarget target) +409
System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics.GetExpandedEnvironmentVariable(String name,     EnvironmentVariableTarget target) +8
System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics.SetModulePath() +65
System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext.InitializeCommon(AutomationEngine engine, PSHost hostInterface) +590
System.Management.Automation.AutomationEngine..ctor(PSHost hostInterface, RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration, InitialSessionState iss) +89
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace.DoOpenHelper() +8062968
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.CoreOpen(Boolean syncCall) +406
```

Only with some "IISRESET" I can execute any PS scripts through the ASP.NET application again. I reproduced the behavior with a new and trivial ASP.NET project on the production environment. I never get this error with test programs like console applications - only in ASP.NET. Indeed I have some lock()... around the execution code because someone on the web wrote that CreateRunspace is not thread safe but all this happens with only one user on the ASP.NET with only one process but only after some thousand executions.

I think this happens during RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace() or the subsequent runspace.Open(). This only happens on production environment with a windows server 2008R2 and IIS7.

I detected some eventlog (Application) entries before the "Object reference not set". I already deleted them, but I am quite sure this entries are related. Short before the first "Object reference not set" error was reported there was an event id 1530 that stated that some HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry key is locked by another process, similar like:

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other
>   applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The
>   applications or services that hold your registry file may not function
>   properly afterwards.

I have to say that I had some scheduled tasks beside the ASP.NET application that start powershell scripts as well under the same user account than the app pool was using. I now changed the user account of the app pool to a copy of the old one (both are windows 2008R2 domain users) and I can not reproduce the error now.

I will keep you informed if the error occurs again!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about configuring a Private Memory Limit or Virtual Memory Limit on your .NET AppPool? How about recycling the AppPool after a particular number of requests have been made (eg. over 9000)? It sounds like, since you're running the code so many times, it might be hitting some sort of memory limit within the Common Language Runtime (CLR).

[image: IIS AppPool Settings]

Comment: Thank you but there was no memory issue.